# Roadside Assistance For US Travel

Tags: automobiles

I'm curious for people who travel with their automobile frequently, what services offer the best roadside assistance for in-USA state travel (among states).  The main three concerns I have are:

1. Flat tires.
2. Car issues needing repair or preventing from further travel.
3. Being stranded, or waiting more than two hours for assistance, due to car issues.

I realize some services may offer other benefits, but with those three concerns, who offers the best insurance - meaning a company that covers those concerns quickly and cost-effectively?

Comment: "best insurance" is going to be subjective.  Could you clarify what you mean by that? The cheapest? The fastest response? The one in the most states? As it stands, the question is a bit subjective, and might get closed :/

Comment: Are you talking about for people living in the US? Or for people visiting from other countries?

Comment: @Karlson People living and traveling in the US.

Comment: Check AAA Gold membership

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases I think what you are asking for would be fulfilled by AAA (aaa.com), they aren't an insurance per say, but the offer quick roadside assistance across the United States.